An algebra structure over a perfect field
When I read some paper, I see the following word:
When $k$ is a perfecr field, a finite dimension $k$-algebra $A$ can be writted as $S\oplus \rm{rad}(A)$, where $S$ is the maximal semisimple subalgebra of $B$, $\rm{rad}(A)$ is the Jacobson radical of $A$.
But I can't prove it and find its proof, so I want to ask for an prove about it.

This is called the Wedderburn-Malcev theorem.

See here and its references. You should find this if you search.

Thank you very much!
